# Policy document for object for AWS s3 - What ACL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

What i want to accomplish is sending file direct from browser to s3 with signature-v4. I have problem with constructing policy document for object

From this:
https://blog.shikisoft.com/signing-aws-s3-uploads-with-signature-v4-ruby-on-rails-angularjs/

I can see how this document should look:

```
Base64.encode64(
    {
      "expiration" => 1.hour.from_now.utc.xmlschema,
      "conditions" => [
        { "bucket" =>  bucket },
        [ "starts-with", "$key", "" ],
        { "acl" => "private" },
        [ "starts-with", "$Content-Type", "" ],
        {"x-amz-algorithm" => x_amz_algorithm },
        {"x-amz-credential" => x_amz_credential },
        {"x-amz-date" => x_amz_date},
        [ "content-length-range", 0, 524288000 ]
      ]
    }.to_json
```

I dont know what ACL should i use.

**I want to give user permission only to upload a file with certain .extension(s), and after this user shoudnt be able to delete it or even read it. The permission should be only for that file**

Here is a list of ACL permissions (I belive it is right place )
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

Can I achive somehow permission only for upload, only for delete, only for read, only for read and delete for one file ? The other question is Content Type that I belive should be generated based on extension.

Please forgive me if I lack some basic concepts

**EDIT 1**

I didnt mention that I want to use multipart upload and from docs of aws
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html

beside `s3:getObject`, `s3:putObject`, I need to give `s3:ListMultipartUploadParts` also

How can I restrict it only to files or folders ? The case is that every user has private files and should have access only to files that he owns

Answer (score 1):

I believe the granularity of what you're trying to obtain would be easier to accomplish by including some other means. What I suggest is a policy with AWS IAM. (That is, I'm going to give info about solving this problem with policies, because I'm not sure it can be accomplished with ACL alone as specifically as you'd like.)

From Amazon: "A policy defines the AWS permissions that you can assign to a user, group, or role. You can create and edit a policy in the visual editor and using JSON."

With the policy, you can specify the privileges all the way down to the specific service, command, resources, and requests.

Some examples of these policies:

```
s3 service, putObject only, arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.jpg only
s3 service, deleteObject only, arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.png only
```

The first allows uploading .jpg files to that bucket only, and the second allows deleting .png files from that bucket only. You can create these policies with raw json, but I'm not going to include that because I think you'll understand better by using their interface for it. [image: Example showing the putObject policy.]

You can make these policies to allow for multiple buckets and multiple file types, if there is more than one you'd like to allow. You can also mix and match the actions, i.e. putObject only, deleteObject only, getObject only, or getObject and deleteObject only, etc.

To use such a created policy, you'll want to record the access id and secret key. I see you mentioned doing this in the browser; do you have server interactions? It's not particularly safe to hardcode your keys in client side code. I would suggest having the keys on the server and having your server code generate temporary credentials matching the policy that it passes to the client to perform the action. AWS temporary credentials allow an expiration time with a minimum of 15 minutes, so this can provide some added security as well.

You can read more about IAM policies here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html

Hope that helps.

edit: one last thing. You'll also want to setup your CORS configuration for the involved buckets, if you haven't. This can restrict what domains can perform the actions (if you'd like) and allow the interactions from the client that has the temporary credentials you make. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://yoursite.com</AllowedOrigin> (or * for any)
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod> (the methods allowed on the bucket)
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3600</MaxAgeSeconds> 
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader> (information you need exposed to client)
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> 
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can read about CORS configurations here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

If this answer is off base for you, I might suggest a more middle ground. Like validating the file type with your code and using the ACL policy for the more general permissions regarding the transaction. Cheers

Comment: thank you for respond. Yes I have server interactions for making signature, then i return it as json and start uploading form with attached signature-policy so my keys are not exposed. Ok so I could create IAM for every kind of action, does it mean that I will have SECRET KEYS for each IAM ? Does it mean that I only need to generate signature(with proper keys) without policy document attached ? Or can i combine two of it and attach another rule like defining a 'start-with' to name the file the way I want. I belive then i restrict access to particular file. Every file will have diffrent owner

Comment: Okay, good. Yes, every unique policy would have it's own access credentials that you would use to generate temporary credentials. Something in your code like `uploadOnlyPolicyId = <id>` and `deleteOnlyPolicyId = <id>` etc etc. Unfortunately, I haven't used AngularJS or ruby on rails for this, my experience lies with JavaScript and PHP. I do not attach a policy document myself, because it's not necessary, although I can't speak for your setup. I don't see why you couldn't have both, I suppose? Why do you need the `starts-with` if you can manipulate and choose the s3 key you assign to the file?

Comment: I think i need to look more into those IAM policies. If i build IAM with getObject policy, I want it to be for only one special object(that user owns). Maybe should I create those IAM policies on the fly but i feel there is a limit. The problem is that getObject, deleteObject IAM policies needs to be for particular files and that would be mad

Comment: ... and that would be mad to make IAM policy for every file, thats why i want to combine 2 to have kinda "authenticated request". Or again im missing something

Comment: And sorry I've been doing it and I skipped a step in my explanation - you create the policy and create a programmatic-access-only user that has that policy applied to them, and that user has the secret key not the policy itself. It all feels the same after a while:)
I may not be understanding your project. Each policy is for a set of privileges, as in my original answer. This can specify the allowed file type, but breaking it down to file by file is too granular. (That is - one policy for upload only privilege, one for delete only privilege, etc etc)

Comment: each IAM user has the secret key but i cant create "IAM user" for each #User of my page. Its basic setup. Users own private files, so when I use some IAM policy for example for Delete, I should be allowed to delete only files that i own. How to acomplish that ? I should restrict access to only that file/path.

Comment: @hodiecode It sounds like what would be best for you is creating subdirectory's in your S3 bucket per user? Like mybucket/user1/, mybucket/user2/ 
When you generate your credentials, it should be easier to restrict to these sub-buckets.

Comment: Note: I call them sub-buckets, but buckets really are flat. It's more of a key that is pre-pended to each object, and makes it look like folders/directories in the UI. Clarifying to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks, i read about it, yes, there is no folders in bucket really...only keys that can immitate folder I forgot to tell that I will upload in chunks therefore I need to sign headers for each chunk not policy doc. It is actually more save because I can check on backend if there are proper headers and proper method. So if I give permission for PUT it works like policy without time access. There can be additional headers like qqfilesize or something like this that will help validate the file that actually can be accepted.

Comment: therefore there is a path/to_file so it works like presigned_url kind of. I will post my explenation when I do the job, if anyone will need it

Comment: @hodiecode Awesome. I hope my answer and follow up was able to help you get in that good direction. Cheers:)

Comment: Yes u help me pointing me to use IAM :) u can look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845773/signing-headers-for-upload-in-chunks-in-fineuploader-php-example-aws-s3 if u have time since u php :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173240/discussion-between-michael-conard-and-hodiecode).